# The Snap verison of GIMP doesn't "see" recent files

Tags: snap, gimp

I've recently switched to the Snap version of GIMP (2.10.22) and ran into the following problem.

Whenever I want to open a recent file saved by a different app in Ubuntu, I'm used to clicking "Open file" and then the "Recent" tab. This has been very straightforward and convenient.

However, the Snap version of Gimp does not "see" those files. Likewise, files saved by the Snap version of Gimp aren't perceived as "recent" by the other apps.

This is very inconvenient and I'm wondering whether it's a Snap limitation, or something that could be easily fixed. My OS is Ubuntu 20.04.

Comment: It's because snaps have a security sandbox policy with "no access to system resources outside of the snap", you can read more here: https://snapcraft.io/docs/security-sandboxing

Comment: @codlord Thanks for the link, is there any way around it?

Answer (score 2):

I used to have the same problem with a flatpak version, which I solved by replacing the `~/.local/share` directory in the flatpak filesystem by a softlink to my real `~/.local/share`. The "recent files" list is actually in `~/.local/share/recently-used.xbel` but you cannot link only the file because it is updated by copy/erase/rename and a link to the file wouldn't survive long.

I eventually ditched the flatpak version because it had other restrictions I could not live with (no access to removable media, and at the time, no access to the real `/tmp` (had its own... so I could not use Gimp from other apps that share files by putting them in `/tmp` (screen captures, etc...)).